# Is there a replacement for the Leopard software accentuer on Lion?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

Back on leopard there was a extremely useful application called "accentuer"
which would through a service add all french accents to a given text. I was doing an almost perfect job at it too.

Would anyone know what happened to this application, if it has been ported to OS X Lion or better an alternative?

My queries on google does not return anything suitable for this use.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found this application; it is now called reacc:
http://rali.iro.umontreal.ca/rali/?q=node/1229

This application is brilliant for people like me who write french with 
a US keyboard: its almost magic.

Unfortunately it is still not ported to Lion. Pity!